# How to solve the error of router not found where I did defined it

Tags: ajax, express, router

I am trying to pull some information from the database by ajax call and render it to html.
This is my ajax function:

```
function getActor(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            const actorList = jsonToTable(this.response, 'default');
            document.getElementById('tbody').innerText = actorList;
        }
    }
    console.log("getActor called");
    xhttp.open('GET','/actor', true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

This is my router:

```
router.get('/actor', function(req, res){
  console.log("router.get /actor called");
  req.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    if(err){
      res.sendStatus(500);
      return;
    }
    var query = "USE mydb; SELECT first_name, last_name FROM actor;";
    connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields){
      connection.release();
      if(err){
        res.sendStatus(500);
        return;
      }
      res.json(rows);
    })
  })
});
```

The console statement inside getActor is called but an error is reported:

```
"GET /actor" Error (404): "Not found"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The problem causing a 404 is outside the code you're showing us.  Please show the code that connects your router to your Express server.  That's likely where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I solved this problem by deleting a previously added app.use(express.static('../public', {index: 'actor.html'}))

Comment: OK, you can either write an answer to your own question (yes, you can answer your own questions) or you can delete the question.   Please pick one of those options so that your question isn't just left hanging out here unresolved forever.  Do not put the resolution into the question - that's not how things work here. Questions are for questions and answers are for answers.

Answer (score 0):

just a followup here.
I solved this problem by deleting a previously added line:

```
app.use(express.static('../public', {index: 'actor.html'}))
```